# Reformatting old m2 nvme ssd with windows OS with active partition

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, format

I have recently installed windows 10 to a new M2 NVME SSD, I didn't use the previous one with OS boot as I also installed it into a new motherboard. When everything was up and working, I also installed the old one into the m2 slot.

[image: DISK DRIVES]

But when I was about to reformat the old ssd, it had the `Active and Primary partition` label to it. I checked out the `Mark Partition as Active` for the new drive but since it wasn't the "Primary Partition" it was greyed out.

[image: greyed out]

So for my question: Can I format my old OS boot drive regardless of it not being the active/primary partition or should I do something else to transfer the label to my main OS drive?

Comment: You do understand we don’t know which disk is your original disk and which one is your new disk, right?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry if I wasn't clear, the old disk (DISK 2) has the Active and Primary Partition as per screenshot.

Comment: Disk 1 is the only disk that is required for Windows to boot.

Comment: Yes it is the only one. But Disk 1 doesn't have the active and primary partition so I wasn't sure if I could just reformat Disk 2 without doing anything else